# Understanding 'self' and setting self to super

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been following a number of tutorials and i am falling down with self. Can anyone help please?

I have the following init, which is an instance method.

```
- (id) initWithScore:(int) s {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        score = s;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Now reading through the code i set the self to the super init, hence self is now pointing to super. I then check if self is valid and set score equal to the value i sent on my InitWIthScore.  I have got this so far.

But now i return self which points to the super, so how am i returning my subclass?

Hence, lets say that somebody calls my class passing in 100, my code is returning the super not the class so how does it work? How does the calling code have value of 100 in score?

of course, yes it does work but i have no idea why :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This construct allows the initializer (both the `super` initializer and the one you are writing) with a way of failing - `nil` is returned if the object cannot be initialized. That is also why you check for `nil` in your `init` after calling `super`.

Both `self` and `super` point to the same data structure in memory, namely your object that you have allocated. The difference is in the language semantics of these special pointers:

When `self` is used, the Objective-C compiler will start method and overload resolution at your current type.

When `super` is used, the Objective-C compiler will start method and overload resolution at the immediate super type of your class. In other words, `super` is just semantics for being able to call a method in your super class even though the same method exists in your current class.

In other words (slightly simplified), `super` treats the memory location as if it were an instance of the super class (e.g. the type you subclassed, often `NSObject`), while `self` treats the memory location as a regular pointer to the type you have defined.

If you print `super` and `self` in the debugger, you will see they point to the same memory location.

Comment: great!, thats what i was looking for .. So self in me :-) thats good, but super in me as well? i though super would be the superclass? i.e. NSObject?

Comment: so self = [super init];    now self is equal to my super class of NSObject, or its equal to me but thats where i get confused, coming form a .net/java background. If i call to my super class and do an init then the super is in fact nsobject isn't it

Comment: @Martin, I updated the answer a bit, hope it clarifies. If you have a class `Foo` that inherits `NSObject` then `Foo` is also an `NSObject` - the is-a relationship. `self` and `super` points to the same memory but treats it different when resolving.

Answer (score 3):

The whole object creation call looks a bit like this:

```
SomeClass *foo = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithScore:100];
```

Now the first thing that happens is calling `[SomeClass alloc]`. This will create a structure for `SomeClass` in memory and return a pointer to it. Next comes the initialization stuff, where `self` is the pointer from the previous step. Therefore `self` points to an object of class `SomeClass`.

The assignment looks a bit strange, though:

```
self = [super init];
```

In most cases `[super init]` won’t change `self`, it will just return the pointer created by `[SomeClass alloc]`. But the assignment pattern allows for two extra options:

1. The superclass `init` can signal a construction error by returning `nil`, in which case all following initializers bail out and you get a `nil` object.
2. The superclass initializer might decide to return a different `self` pointer, for example if there’s some elaborate caching being done. The pointer should again point to an object of `SomeClass` type, so that your code works (you can access `score` etc).

I suggest that you read [The How and Why of Cocoa Initializers](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html) by Mike Ash. And yes, it’s very good to realize that `self` and `super` both point to the same object, as noted by driis.

Comment: I think he wants to know why he does this anyway. The reason for this is that `[super init]` is allowed to return a different pointer, for example `nil` if it fails to initialize itself.

Comment: Hi zoul, yes i have the object creation and i understand what i don't understand (see code snippet in question above) is that in the initiWithScore, the self is being assigned to [super init] so it now has the super and returns this super to the calling client then how does the calling client (your code) have the contents of "SomeClass" when super was returned.